# Setting DTR high, RTS low using Linux bash?

Tags: stty

I have a serial device that has no flow control, but is powered from the **RS232** port by holding the **RTS high** and **DTR low**

I was hoping to read from this device using a simple bash script, but can't find any way to set the handshaking lines, using stty or otherwise, to allow for the above configuration.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: It is certainly possible but it requires support in the device driver.  What device driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using one of these:http://www.moxa.com/product/UC-7112_UC-7110.htm   I could always "fix" it in hardawre, simply wiring these lines directly to a power supply...but nicer not to if possible!

Comment: MOXA MU860 UART Device Driver version 2.0
Tty devices major number = 30
Register IO misc ver1.0 OK.
Generic Moxa RC7000 RTC Driver v1.0
Register Moxa misc ver1.0 OK.
initialized. (nowayout=0)
initialized. (debug=0)
(C)2004-2005 Moxa Inc. Crypto Driver at /dev/mxcrypto 10
Serial: 8250/16550 driver $Revision: 1.90 $ 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
ttyS0 at I/O 0xf9820000 (irq = 31) is a 16550A
ttyS1 at I/O 0xf9820020 (irq = 31) is a 16550A

Comment: Are there specific commands you can send to the device driver to control those lines? Since the device driver command interface is quite low level you might need a small program to format and send the commands.

Comment: did you settle on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer about setting RTS without touching DTR, because I don't have any DTR pin on my dongle; but, trying to set RTS was already very tricky un pure shell.

You may need to play with stty crtscts and clocal flags.

I have published a detailed answer here:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8132756.html#8132756

Here is the short version:

```
#!/bin/bash
MySerialPort="/dev/ttyUSB0"
MyLatency="2"
echo "#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
main()
{ int fd; fd = open(\"${MySerialPort}\",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
int RTS_flag; RTS_flag = TIOCM_RTS;
ioctl(fd,TIOCMBIS,&RTS_flag);
sleep (${MyLatency});
ioctl(fd,TIOCMBIC,&RTS_flag);
close(fd); } " | tcc -run -
```

Note that sending data on TX will probably mess RTS; see the Gentoo forum for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying something similar here.
I used the ioctls. Then measured with a multimeter.
this is what I found:

```
  dsrv=TIOCM_DTR;//this sets RTS to -11.7?
  dsrv=TIOCM_RTS;//sets DTR -11.7
  ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIS, &dsrv);

  dsrv=TIOCM_DTR;//this sets RTS to 11.7?
  dsrv=TIOCM_RTS;//sets DTR 11.7
  ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIC, &dsrv);
```

It is somewhat weird...

Comment: Please ignore my prev post. It's incorrect. I got tripped up by open() and close twiddling the DTR line aswell as the inversion. opening sets DTR to a negative voltage, as does clearing TIOCM_DTR. setting TIOCM_DTR sets a positive voltage, and is also observed on the closed port.

Answer (score -1):

socat controls DTR when hucpcl=1

(Atmel EDBG USB Serial needs DTR high)

```
sleep 1; while true; do echo -en "\x01\x02"; sleep 0.1; done | socat -T1 -t1 - /dev/ttyUSB0,hupcl=1,raw,b1000000,cs8,echo=0
```

man socat   - may be find more solutions for your serial problem.

Comment: Please, explain why & how your code works so that less experienced programmers can fully understand It